# how to programmatically compile code in text box using c# compiler

Tags: c#

[Image Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7Ooz.png)

I want Run String Code In C# Compiler 
Please Ineed Help For Complet My project

Comment: It will be more readable and workable, if you can provide the materials you wrote in Image, just in here as a code segment.

Answer (score 1):

Your project description is a bit short: You want to execute c# code in a windows application and it should be entered in a text box. Maybe using a scripting engine like [CS-Script](http://www.csscript.net/) could be a solution, too.

1. You can test the code entered in the text box and execute it there.
2. and you can save the text in a file and execute it using a second application as "script executer"

Comment: I like your solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

1. Prepare the code you wanted to compile.
2. Write it to a temp file.
3. Kick off csc.exe

Read more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx

Comment: I want Compile To Win Application This Not Answered

Comment: And I think you can do it. using my solution.